# Notebook Keyboard is not properly handed

Tags: keyboard, acer

I tried every variants of ubuntu and I can't find a way to use my keyboard properly.

The main issue is that AltGr is opening up the context menu on every application (basically, right click behavior). AltGR and Right win key are the same key, and every ubuntu (or even arch with kfce) only recognize the right win key, not the altgr (which I need to type the 'commercial at' (arobase)) key which is AltGr + 0

(basically I can't use any character accessible via Alt Gr)

http://www.laptopmag.com/images/uploads/3870/g/Acer-Aspire-S7-G16.jpg

How to fix that ?

Thanks !

model is Aspire S7 391

Answer (score 1):

To enable the Alt Gr feature, press Fn key and Menu Key together, then the "Menu" Key will act like "Alt Gr".

http://acer-au.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/29284/~/aspire-s7-391-alt-gr-key-function-added